# wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) when running capistrano (ruby)

Tags: ruby, capistrano

```
desc "Takes a database dump from remote server"
  task :backup do
     invoke 'db:backup_name'
      on roles(:db) do

   run "mysqldump -u #{fetch(:db_username)} -p#{fetch(:db_password)} #{fetch(:db_database)} > #{shared_path}/db_backups/#{fetch(:backup_filename)}.sql"

     system('mkdir -p db_backups')
     download! "#{fetch(:backup_file)}", "db_backups/#{fetch(:backup_filename)}.sql"

     within release_path do
       execute :rm, "#{fetch(:backup_file)}"
     end

  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

on this line:

```
run "mysqldump -u #{fetch(:db_username)} -p#{fetch(:db_password)} #{fetch(:db_database)} > #{shared_path}/db_backups/#{fetch(:backup_filename)}.sql"
```

If I puts the contents of this and run this on the remote server - it works fine. Really not sure why ruby throws this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [backticks](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/18/backtick-system-exec-in-ruby.html) instead:

```
`mysqldump -u #{fetch(:db_username)} -p#{fetch(:db_password)} #{fetch(:db_database)} > #{shared_path}/db_backups/#{fetch(:backup_filename)}.sql`
```